# collecting info from dropdwon list and send it to e-mail

Tags: php

i got one question. i need to collect the information from the dropdows and send e-mail with that info. How can i do this?I want when they select what they want to generate mail and send it and to write this mail and his date in DB table.

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "toner_orders";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT name FROM printers";
$sql2 = "SELECT pieces FROM toners";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."        </option>";
    }
echo "</select>";    
echo "<select>";
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['peices'] ."'>" . $row['pieces'] ."       </option>";

}
echo "</select>";   


?> 
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "toner_orders";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT name FROM printers";
$sql2 = "SELECT pieces FROM toners";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";   
echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['peices'] ."'>" . $row['pieces'] ."     </option>";

}
echo "</select>";   


?>
<br><br>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "toner_orders";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT name FROM printers";
$sql2 = "SELECT pieces FROM toners";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."    </option>";

}
echo "</select>";   
echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['peices'] ."'>" . $row['pieces'] ."    </option>";

}
 echo "</select>";  


?> 
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "toner_orders";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$sql = "SELECT name FROM printers";
$sql2 = "SELECT pieces FROM toners";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";   
echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['peices'] ."'>" . $row['pieces'] ."    </option>";

}
 echo "</select>";  


?>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you're asking a lot for one question. tackle one thing at a time. firstly, work out what you get when someone submits a form. hint `print_r($_GET)`. Before that, give each select a name, in order the server gets the info you submit, e.g. `<select name="printer">`

Comment: To avoid using several times your connection, you can create a file to store the data, also, to send an email you have mail() function try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and you don't have any name input to post or get when you hit the submit button